# Make a hints environment (appear with something like `\ifhints`)

Tags: environments, conditionals, exam

I use the `exam`-class a lot, I especially like the solution environments.
My documents contain questions and solutions but by changing `\printanswers` in the preamble I can easily switch showing the solutions or not.

I would like to do the same for **hints**. I would like something like:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
%\ifprintanswers
\ifprinthints

\begin{document}
  \begin{questions}
    \question Prove $e^{i\pi} +1 = 0$.

    \begin{hints}
      Consider $e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i\sin \theta$.
    \end{hints}

    \begin{solution}
      duh.
    \end{solution}
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

I have made a custom class which is based on the `exam`class but loads in some packages and custom commands, which commands should I add to implement this functionality? Could someone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One very easy way of doing this is to use the [version](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/version) package. If you add the lines:

```
\newenvironment{hints}{\textbf{Hint}}{}
\excludeversion{hints}
```

then your hints will not appear. Comment out `\excludeversion{hints}` (or use `\includeversion{hints}`), and they will magically reappear. Here a full MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{version}

\newenvironment{hints}{\textbf{Hint}}{}
\excludeversion{hints}% turn hints off

\begin{document}
  \begin{questions}
    \question Prove $e^{i\pi} +1 = 0$.

    \begin{hints}
      Consider $e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i\sin \theta$.
    \end{hints}

    \begin{solution}
      duh.
    \end{solution}
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

A second way of doing this, which is closer in spirit to your question, is using the [environ](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ) package to define your hint environment. With this approach you first define a new if-statement, say `\ifhinting`, and then use `\hintingtrue` and `\hintingfalse` to turn the hints on and off:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{exam}
\usepackage{environ}

\newif\ifhinting\hintingtrue % hints are on by defautl
\NewEnviron{hints}{\ifhinting\textbf{Hint} \BODY\fi}

\begin{document}
  \begin{questions}
    \question Prove $e^{i\pi} +1 = 0$.

    \begin{hints}
      Consider $e^{i\theta} = \cos \theta + i\sin \theta$.
    \end{hints}

    \begin{solution}
      duh.
    \end{solution}
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

The `\NewEnviron` command defines a new environment but it slurps the contents of the environment into the macro `\BODY` and so lets you do things with it, such as ignore it when `\hintingfalse` is true.

One advantage of this approach is that you can turn the hints on and off in different parts of the documents (this could also be viewed a disadvantage as you have to check everywhere!).